# S3 Replication - s3:PutReplicationConfiguration

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have been attempting to introduce S3 bucket replication into my existing project's stack.  I kept getting an 'API: **s3:PutBucketReplication** Access Denied' error in CloudFormation when updating my stack through my CodeBuild/CodePipeline project after adding the Replication rule on the source bucket + S3 replication role.  For testing, I've added full S3 permission ( s3:* ) to the CodeBuild Role for all resources ( "*" ), as well as full S3 permissions on the S3 replication role -- again I got the same result.

Additionally, I tried running a stand-alone, stripped down version of the CF template (so not updating my existing application infrastructure stack) - which creates the buckets (source + target) and the S3 replication role.  It was deployed/run through CloudFormation while logged in with my Admin role via the console and again I got the same error as when attempting the deployment with my CodeBuild role in CodePipeline.

As a last ditch sanity check, again being logged in using my admin role for the account, I attempted to perform the replication setup manually on buckets that I created using the S3 console and I got the below error:

**You don't have permission to update the replication configuration
You or your AWS admin must update your IAM permissions to allow s3:PutReplicationConfiguration, and then try again. Learn more about Identity and access management in Amazon S3 API response
Access Denied**

[image]

I confirmed that my role has full S3 access across all resources.  This message seems to suggest to me that the permission **s3:PutReplicationConfiguration** may be different then other S3 permissions somehow - needing to be configured with root access to the account or something?

Also, it seems strange to me that CloudFormation indicates the  **s3:PutBucketReplication** permission, where as the S3 console error references the permission **s3:PutReplicationConfiguration**.  There doesn't seem to be an IAM action for s3:PutBucketReplication (ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html) only s3:PutReplicationConfiguration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the required permission `s3:PutReplicationConfiguration` was actually being blocked by a preventive ControlTower Guard Rail that was put in place on the OU the AWS account exists in.  Unfortunately, this DENY is not visible as a user from anywhere within the AWS account itself - as it exists outside of any Permission Boundary or IAM Policy.  This required some investigation from our internal IT team to identify the source of the DENY from the Guard Rail Control.

**Reference:** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/controltower/latest/userguide/elective-guardrails.html#disallow-s3-ccr

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked Permission Boundary? Is this in a corporate control tower or stand alone account?

Deny always wins so if you have a Permission Boundary that excludes some actions even when you have explicitly allowed it you may run into issues like this.

Answer (score -1):

add "iam:passrole" to the iam policy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).